# Permission denied on Connect with table only privileges set

Tags: mysql

(originally asked on StackOverflow but it was suggested that I ask here)
 - MySQL 5.1.41 community (Windows Server 2003)
 - .Net/Connector 6.1.3.0

I've just created a new user and rather than grant schema privileges I've granted rights on only specific tables.  In other words, there are NO global or schema level permissions set, only permissions set are for a couple specific tables.  This seemed like a perfectly acceptable policy and from what I've ready MySQL will search:

1. global
2. schema/DB
3. Table
4. Column

for appropriate permissions.  However when I try to open a connection to the server using this new user account I receive a permission denied error.

> Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxx'

I have tried with several different clients and the result is the same.  I have also checked the server log and there are no additional details, just this:

> 110816 10:23:15 543 Connect xxxxxx@192.168.1.xxx on xxxxxxxx 543 Init DB Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxx'"

If I grant SELECT on the schema in question I can connect just fine.  Am I misunderstanding the way the permission system works or should it work like I think?

Answer (score 2):

If you add a user with a manual insert into mysql.user, you need to run `flush privileges` before you can login with that user. If you use a `GRANT` to create the user, the flush is automatically done for you.

Here's an example insert:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (user, host, password) 
  VALUES ('user', 'localhost', password('yourpassword'));
```

Comment: The user was created with MySQL Administrator so I checked the logs to see what it did.  It called flush privileges.  plus I have been able to connect with this user WHEN I grant SELECT tot he schema - So maybe this is REQUIRED?

Comment: I can add a user with a direct insert statement, flush privileges and login without difficulty, even with no privileges.

Comment: I've never added a user with a sql statement, do you mind posting your statement (with bits redacted) so I can test on my end?

Comment: added the query to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the statement - I could have tried myself but wanted to be sure I used what you did.  I ran: " INSERT INTO mysql.user (user, host, password, ssl_cipher, x509_issuer, x509_subject) VALUES ('user1', 'localhost', 'password1', '','','');" and still get access denied when trying to connect

Comment: BTW, note that I had to add the ssl_cipher, x509_* fields.

Comment: did you put your password in the password() function?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what you need to know: No access to the database. Can't access the table without accessing the enclosing database, so grant appropriate permissions to the latter. It's kind of like being granted access to a file on a server but denied access to the server itself.

Comment: I just didn't believe that MySQL would REQUIRE a user to have SELECT access for the entire database in order to connect.  You can't "take away" permissions at the table level so if I want to limit a user to only select a subset of tables I can't.

Comment: also sreimer seems to have been able to create a user with no permissions granted and still be able to connect.

Comment: @Steve, you've read more into sreimer's answer than what is there. Simply being able to log in to the server does not imply access to databases or tables.

Comment: I see your point, however I can't even login/connect so I was holding out hope that once connected I would be able to work with objects that I have permissions for (e.g. select from table foo)  To be crystal clear: Are you saying that I must grant permission to the schema to be able to perform CRUD operations with specific tables within that database?  And by extension grant select to all tables within that database?

Comment: @Steve, if you can't even log in you need to solve that first, then work your way through the other two layers. Never having restricted a user to just a table I'm not sure just what rights they need on the database to be able to access the table but I'm sure that would be covered in the documentation.